# Suppress RuntimeBinderException messages from dynamic types

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I've recently started using a private NuGet server to manage my organization's internal libraries. This means in order to step into our own code that is in a library, I need to disable "Enable Just My Code" in debugging options since we aren't referring to the projects directly any more. This is a pretty hefty MVC project that uses dynamic types and `ExpandoObjects` in addition to `ViewBag`. I get two `RuntimeBinderExceptions` for every single use of a dynamic type... which is a lot. This appears to be normal behavior from what I've read. Normal it may be, but useful it is not.

My first thought was to disable this particular exeption in the Debug-> Exceptions dialog. The exception is not to be found there. I can't figure out any way to be able to step outside the projects referenced directly, without also opening myself up to these exceptions. (And all manner of other low-level framework exceptions that I don't want to hear about, but this is the biggest offender by far).

What's the best way to deal with this?

Edit: This is the problem. How do I stop this with "Enable Just My Code" disabled?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add additional "exception" names (existing in your own code or other libraries)...so long as you know the exception's fully qualified type name.

Managing Exception with the Debugger
[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6C7Y.png)

### In Visual Studio 2010

Via the `Debug | Exceptions...` dialog.

[image]

- Use the `Add` button to add a new exception under the `Common Language Runtime Exceptions` group and call it `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException`

[image]

- then just make sure `Thrown` and `User-Handled` are NOT ticked - thus causing the first chance exception to be ignored, rather than being caught by the debugger.

---

### In Visual Studio 2017

Via the `Debug | Windows | Exception Settings...` panel

[image]

[image]

- Use + to add the new exception name

[image]

- make sure it's unticked

Comment: Hi - thanks for your response! I don't care about exceptions being logged in the output window. I need to stop the debugger itself from stopping code execution when these exceptions are thrown. See edit. (That's from the main project!)

Comment: I don't think that's a reasonable solution - it would require extensive code modification, and some libraries I may not be able to or want to recompile. It means I can no longer step through the code without using breakpoints which is a big part of why I want to do this in the first place.

Comment: Holy crapnuts. That works. I feel as if a great weight has been lifted.

Comment: Unfortunately, the messages still show up in the debug output. That's annoying because the red messages fly by and I have to go searching to find out if they're something I need to worry about or not.

Comment: You could go to "Tools | Options" then "Debugging | Output Window"....try in "General Output Settings" turn "Exception Messages" to "Off" .... or alternatively, Right Click in the "Debug" Output Window to show a menu....and untick the Exception Messages