# Machine-specific (??) behavior parsing JSON string into DynamicJsonObject

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio-2013

I have a chunk of code that runs as expected without debugger, but when I run it under debugger, it works on one machine and fails on another. Both machines have pretty much the same setup: Windows 8, .NET Framework 4.5, Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Update 4, I run the same console application on both machines.

The code parses this string containing JSON:

```
{"success":true,"doAlternative":false,"errors":null,"content":null}
```

into a dynamic object using System.Web.Helpers:

```
dynamic result = Json.Decode(jsonString);
```

Then I access the `success` field of the result object:

```
if ( result.success != true )
```

On one machine (I remind: the issue is when running under the debugger), this just works. On another, I get RuntimeBinderException:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException occurred
  _HResult=-2146233088
  _message='System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJsonObject' does not contain a definition for 'success'
  HResult=-2146233088
  IsTransient=false
  Message='System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJsonObject' does not contain a definition for 'success'
  Source=Microsoft.CSharp
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderController.SubmitError(CError pError)
  InnerException:
```

On the "working" machine, when I type `result` in the Immediate window, I get:

```
{System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJsonObject}
    base: {System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJsonObject}
```

while on the "failing" machine, I get this:

```
{System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJsonObject}
    base: {System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJsonObject}
    _values: Count = 4
```

And here is the most strange bit: playing in Immediate window on the failing machine, typing `result["success"]` for the first time gives this:

```
Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException occurred
  _HResult=-2146233088
  _message=Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJsonObject'
  HResult=-2146233088
  IsTransient=false
  Message=Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'System.Web.Helpers.DynamicJsonObject'
  Source=Microsoft.CSharp
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderController.SubmitError(CError pError)
  InnerException:
```

And then, typing again `result["success"]` for the second time, makes it work! And then `result.success` works too. It would not bother me, but if I don't place breakpoints and just run the application with F5, it fails.

This machine-debugger-specific-behavior is scaring - I'm afraid of putting code in production which has such kind of issues, (it is currently observed only under debugger, but who knows..?) Can someone please shed any light on this?

Comment: Could you provide some information about your execution context (It's best if you can provide code)? Are you decoding the JSON string asynchronously/lazily?

Comment: It is a console application, my code runs under Quartz.Net scheduler, I believe it runs on a regular ThreadPool thread. Nothing special besides that. It is a robot that automates a legacy application, I send HTTP request and then get JSON string in response. Then I need to perse the JSON string to verify that it has field named "success" set to "true". I am adding some code to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OK, I've found the reason - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11439486/suppress-runtimebinderexception-messages-from-dynamic-types).**

Going to Tools > Options > Debugging and checking **Enable Just My Code** effectively resolves the issue.

That checkbox was exactly the difference between the two environments. Tried unchecking it on the "working" machine and got the same exception there, so I can confirm that this behavior is stable and consistent (now I'm happy).

So the problem is only debugger that tries to follow the code being debugged and read members of a dynamic object, while those members are internal to the assembly where the dynamic object was created. That's why it fails under debugger, and that's why it works when running without the debugger.